# HSAB: alkyl halides & carbonyls LUMO energy flaw

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

Hard electrophiles have LUMO of higher energy than soft electrophiles. Alkyl halides are considered to be soft electrophiles while carbonyl compounds are considered to be hard electrophiles. The sigma antibonding C-X orbital of an alkyl halide is higher in energy than the pi antibonding C-O orbital of carbonyls which is in contradiction with the previous statement.

How is this paradox explained?